# file -i test.xlsx returns application/octet-stream instead of real mime type

Tags: 16.04, mime-type

```
$ file -i import_test.xlsx
import_test.xlsx: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

The mime type should be "application/zip" but the command returns "application/octet-stream". This is working in Ubuntu 14.04. Though, I can't remember if I have installed some additional packages to get it working.

Is there some packages that need to be installed in order to get the mime types recognized for office files?

I have already the latest `libfile-mimeinfo-perl`.

Comment: `file` determines the file's type by looking at the first few bytes of the file (see `man magic`). Are you SURE `import_test.xlsx` is what you think?

Comment: Yes, it is an xlsx file I just opened and saved with LibreOffice.

Comment: On ubuntu that 'normally' happen....I have a PHP program handling Upload file (xls, xlsx),,,and the case is the same as yours...so I need to manually add the Mime type to the PHP config